# Limits on requests for production of documents under FRCP

Tags: civil-procedure, subpoena

The FRCP requires that parties make available documents to the party requesting same documents for inspecting and or copying.

But suppose the parties to a civil action are hundreds of miles apart?

As I understand it a request for production does not require the adversary to produce copies.  So how does one go about getting copies of documents?  Does the subpoenaed party have to travel to the requesting party's office to produce the requested documents for inspection and copying?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Federal Rules of Civil Procedure](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_26), Rule 26(g):

> By signing, an attorney or party certifies that to the best of the person's knowledge, information, and belief formed after a reasonable inquiry:...
>   with respect to a discovery request, response, or objection, it is:...
>   neither unreasonable nor unduly burdensome or expensive, considering
>   the needs of the case, prior discovery in the case, the amount in
>   controversy, and the importance of the issues at stake in the action.

Requiring the other party to travel 300 miles might be considered "unduly burdensome".